# Broadcast tx success, but the tx not confirmed

Tags: transactions

curl -X POST   http://10.199.6.34:8732/injection/operation?chain=main -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d  '"04b831bce8c892b39e12cee3684f12ece0c4e9c816def919fa550bd50805b292080000e7fb71f07fb0a5ac3ec398f6ad47c10730d2145f9329bedd04f855ac02a09bd41c00007fb3301cd8e3a926a07183e2a51408e87d82ef79ff00000002030b0d87b883081b19190f18f23c579ac43675abccff8794097f086b8e6c892537a42265c4fe572d3c01733d761d4324e8f79ef763ba3f70c3a7b8d476681ea6640d"'
"opCVDVTDUCSJKtdsQY6meFWbChzUmwTTpFbeTK1bXAA2vhozwWZ"

Comment: curl -X POST   http://10.199.6.34:8732/injection/operation?chain=main -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d  '"8d898cf3fff91f371e7a9c95430bfefce2b08052214c25f257a587e5c5d3654f080000e7fb71f07fb0a5ac3ec398f6ad47c10730d2145ff309bedd04f855ac02e0b1851f00007fb3301cd8e3a926a07183e2a51408e87d82ef79ff00000002030bd6c2aa5f9a5f12ead7d673a730feb64e3c3d0b762befcb781edba1df63041a679dcfd3e69a32c563960984876aafc61ad97e2625445f1b16d98292e685d21b0d"'
"oomx4t5KRiXk4d5jnB1g76bnV7s5p63ZjZD2ZJftGpyGsmL3u7t"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your transactions include enough **Gas Limit**, **Storage Limit** and **Fee**.

Sending transactions to active contracts:

```
storage_limit : 0
gas_limit : 10200
fee : 1282
```

Sending transactions to inactive contracts:

```
storage_limit : 257
gas_limit : 10200
fee : 1282
```